# Get rid of date PID and Package name in Logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I want to remove the date, packagename, and PID in the logcat.

So this:

```
 11-10 14:34:54.747 PID/package-name
```

How can I achieve this? And what if I wanted to indent nested calls? How can I create my own indentation for logging?

Comment: Huh? I'm talking about specifically for development and debugging. I'm sure this is possible. For example go look up a library called `Hugo`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393673/system-out-println-in-android/33393940#33393940

Comment: nice! You should post that as an answer ill accept it